# PrestaShop need zip extension

Tags: php, ubuntu, zip, prestashop

Good afternoon, I apologize for all the inconvenience, I would like to ask about an error that I am getting.

AIt's my first time installing PrestaShop and I'm using Ubuntu for that, along with apache and MySQL.

AAmong several installation guides including in several versions of PrestaShop and in all of them I have the same problem.

"You must install PHP zip extension first"

I have the extension installed, I made changes to my server in the PHP versions, restarted the installation from 0 to everything, but still, I can't give the solution. I don't know if this happened to someone.

I'm really sure I'm doing something wrong, because I don't have much experience on the subject, thanks again.

[image: console image]

[image: console image]

Comment: My Php -v PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2023 18:31:54) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group                           Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: Are you sure that your Prestashop installation is using the same PHP version of your OS? I would definitely check this by placing a phpinfo file in the document root to see if ZIP Extension is detected there.

Comment: interesting, look, if the Zip extension is there, but it is taking me as a reference php8.2.4, when the system tells me that I have 7.4, how do I change this

Comment: it's pretty common to have multiple php versions, especially if you have a server managing panel.

Comment: Apache uses a php module which is not the same as php cli so most likely the php module is missing zip extension.

Comment: The solution was easy, use apt-get purge php8.* And fixed